# How to listen to a *unnamed* Event?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, ethers.js

**I am trying to listen for this event, but it does not have an actual name. Is there a way to Listen for event 0x0511a506 ?**

[image]

Comment: It's not an event, it's a function call. Judging by the data structure, its parameters are 2 addresses and 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generic `subscribe("logs")` handler ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-logs)) and filter by the contract address and event signature (`topics[0]`).

Mind that the `0x0511a506` mentioned in your question is a selector of the parent function that was invoked while the event was emitted, but you're really looking for the event signature - `0x598cd562...` in your case.

```
web3.eth.subscribe("logs", {
    address: "contractAddress",
    topics: [
        "0x598cd562..."
    ]
}, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```